# Process uninitialization

Tags: linux, process, posix

When a process ends, what operations does the operating system take, making it unnecessary to include certain uninitialization code? For instance I know it closes open file descriptors, but what about unmapping mapped files, etc?

Comment: This is bad practice to rely on the OS to take the cleanup actions for you.

Comment: You certainly should not rely on it, but understanding the semantics is important anyway.

Comment: I'd like to challenge the 'bad practice' claims above. You should absolutely clean after yourself if you write library code. However, if you build your software from many small processes each responsible for working with just a few resources and terminate (i.e. how most Unix tools work), you can just as well rely on the OS cleanup and spare some CPU and brain cycles. E.g. calling `free()` costs more than letting OS tear the entire process.

Answer (score 1):

From the linux man page for mmap(1) at http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html

"The region is also automatically unmapped when the process is terminated."

It is perfectly reasonable to rely on this as it is defined behavior.